# How to show that $\phi: \mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{C}) \to V(Y^2 - X^3)$ is no isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, affine-varieties

Consider the polynomial function

$$\phi: \mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{C})\to V(Y^2 - X^3): t \mapsto (t^2, t^3)$$

Show that $\phi$ is a bijective polynomial function, but no isomorphism (= $\phi^{-1}$ is no polynomial function).

I proved that $\phi$ is bijective and $\phi = (X^2, X^ 3)$, thus $\phi$ is a polynomial function. How would I show that $\phi^{-1}$ is no polynomial function?

Comment: Do you know about tangent spaces?

Comment: @LukasKofler No didn't have differential geometry yet.

Comment: Me neither! You can define them purely algebraically and show that the tangent spaces at the origin are different, so the varieties are not isomorphic. I‘m sure there is another proof though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for something elementary. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use that fact that isomorphic varieties have isomorphic coordinate rings.

Consider the coordinate ring of $\Bbb A^1, \Bbb C[t]$. Note that this is a UFD.

On the other hand, the coordinate ring of $V(Y^2 - X^3)$ is $\Bbb C[x, y]/(Y^2 - X^3)$. It is not a UFD since we have $Y^2 = X^3$.

Therefore $\Bbb A^1 \ncong V(Y^2 - X^3)$.

Comment: Thanks. That was very elementary.

Comment: A closely related argument would be to state that the coefficient ring $\Bbb{C}[t]$ is integrally closed (in its field of fractions), but the other coordinate ring is not. This is because $t=Y/X$ is integral over it ($t^2=X$). For curves smoothness is equivalent to coordinate ring being integrally closed. Apologies if you knew about this already.

Comment: I didn't, so it was surely helpful to me :)